# Woocommerce how to add order review/summary

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

How can I add a page/step in which the customer can review his complete order right after he submits it but before he gets to the payment (this step is required by law).

More precisely how can I redirect the form post?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do,
copy the checkout.php from the plugins folder to my theme folder
place a cookie to check if the order has been reviewed

If NOT
Show Review order button

ELSE
show the original check out options

Hope this helps

Comment: The review step must be the last one ... so it is not allowed to review and then go back to cart. The customer should complete the order with a click on the review page (and only there). So the checkout-form-button/checkout-form-target should be redirected to the review page. On the review-page all POST information could be loaded in hidden fields and when the user clicks review-ok the order should be placed. The problem is that the change of the form-target doesn't do anything cause the submit goes via javascript i think ... if i disable js the forms action-attribute is used as target

Comment: I changed the url via the filter woocommerce_get_checkout_url

Comment: Ok it doesn't matter if javascript is enabled or not x.X